# Which request params can be used to tell if a request is coming from Postman vs NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, axios, postman

I am running two identical API requests to a 3rd party API -- one in postman and the other in NodeJS. The API responds with different `set-cookie` headers in Postman vs NodeJS.

I've tried:

- Copying the headers from Postman headers tab into my nodejs request headers.
- Copying headers from the Postman console logs into my nodejs request headers.
- Copying Postman's auto-generated `axios` code.
- `node-fetch` instead of `axios`.
- Turning various settings on/off in Postman.

Every time, the API request in Postman responds with a different set-cookie header than NodeJS. The postman request is receiving the correct session token while the NodeJS request is not.

1. The API server can somehow tell the difference between the two environments, but how?
2. Is postman running on a headless browser so that it can "fool" a server checking for browser runtime?
3. Is postman a true "curl" while nodejs requests are not?
4. Given that the request headers and body are the same in both requests, which variables might be used to differentiate between a postman request and nodejs request?

Comment: Use Fiddler to inspect the requests and compare them. You may have to enable HTTPS traffic decryption. (to make it work in nodejs you need [this](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/knowledge-base/how-to-capture-nodejs-traffic))

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do this without fiddler?

Comment: Why, what's the issue with it? Why does it matter which tool you use for troubleshooting?

Comment: I already knew it was possible to troubleshoot this myself, but I was hoping to find an answer and avoid spending another 10 hours on it (learning a new tool that I'll probably rarely use). That's why I asked on stack overflow.

Comment: Well this is the most straight forward way to find out what the differences are in your particular case, and _much_ easier for you (where your software is running on your own computer) to diagnose with it than for me from possibly the other side of the world. And I think Fiddler is a tool you never want to miss again once you discovered how to use it... it was just a matter of time until you needed to learn how to use it. That's why I suggested it as the most promising way forward... The hardest things to figure out about it are those things I specifically mentioned to make it easier for you

Comment: (Since nobody else answered or commented to this question so far, it's safe to assume there is no obvious solution that jumps to mind remotely without debugging it...)

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure I figured it out, without spending hours debugging it... It seems like this is the big difference https://blog.postman.com/introducing-the-postman-agent-send-api-requests-from-your-browser-without-limits/

Comment: But @CherryDT I appreciate your explanation. Fiddler sounds like a cool tool, and I'll try to find some time to learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this myself, for anyone who comes here searching for answers. Apparently, Postman uses some magic configuration to make requests from the browser while bypassing CORS issues.

They call it the "Postman Agent". It seems like it's probably a local proxy in front of a headless browser with CORS turned off (or something along those lines).

You can read about it here: https://blog.postman.com/introducing-the-postman-agent-send-api-requests-from-your-browser-without-limits/

In my case, the issue wasn't caused by a difference between the requests. It was caused by the way the responses were handled. Postman was showing cookies received in an initial 302 response, and then following the redirect. The NodeJS request was following the redirect but not showing the initial 'set-cookie' header in the final response. As soon as I set `redirect: 'manual'` in nodejs, I could see the correct headers from the initial 302 response.

Comment: Hm but this sounds like the opposite, doesn't it? The agent exists in order to allow sending fully customizable requests just like you can with curl or nodejs, so that there _won't_ be restrictions coming from a browser-like environment. At least so I thought.

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely the intention behind it, but since it's in a headless browser, it has some other effects. In my case, Postman was showing cookies received in an initial 302 response, and then following the redirect. The NodeJS request was following the redirect but not showing the initial 'set-cookie' header in the final response. As soon as I set `redirect: manual` in nodejs, I could see the correct headers from the initial 302 response.

Comment: I think _that_ should be the answer then! The request is the same, but the response was handled differently... In my opinion, it's not really relevant whether postman _agent_ in particular was involved, but rather the subtleties of how the 302 response was handled - and how you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I added that context to the answer